# What is the difference between two join statements in the code?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

In the below code, there are two joins (of course one is commented). I would like to know what is the difference between 
when join is executed before the loop and when join is executed after the loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void ThreadFunction();

int main()
{
    thread ThreadFunctionObj(ThreadFunction);
    //ThreadFunctionObj.join();
    for (int j=0;j<10;++j)
    {
        cout << "\tj = " << j  << endl;
    }
    ThreadFunctionObj.join();
    return 0;
}

void ThreadFunction()
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        cout << "i = " << i  << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want the spawned thread to join with the main thread - before or after the loop? That is the difference.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean that calling join immediately after creating the object is as same as calling a function (ie a synchronous function).

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: It never makes sense to `join()` a thread immediately after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

A `join()` on a thread waits for it to finish execution, your code doesn't continue as long as the thread isn't done. As such, calling `join()` right after starting a new thread defeats the purpose of multi-threading, as it would be the same as executing those two for loops in a serial way. Calling `join()` after your loop in `main()` ensures that both for loops execute in parallel, meaning that at the end of your for loop in your `main()`, you wait for the `ThreadFunction()` loop to be done too. This is the equivalent of you and a friend going out to eat, for example. You both start eating at relatively the same time, but the first one to finish still has to wait for the other (might not be the best example, but hope it does the job).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Oliver for detailed explanation and  example. I just posted the doubt (of purpose getting defeated when join is called immediately after creating the thread). Assuming that my main function runs longer than thread function ( for example, loop for j is till 100000 and loop for i is till only 100. Knowing this, putting join at the end or omitting it does not make any difference. Right? Like, I ordered for an unlimited buffet and my friend for peace of bread, knowing our eating speed is same, me waiting for him does not make sense. This is just a knowledge question but not a practice one.

Comment: Hey, the `join()` function isn't required, but recommended sometimes as this tells the thread object can be safely destroyed after that point (a thread exiting without errors will still be safely terminated though). In most cases, `join()` is omitted when you don't care about its execution, meaning it's a task that has little to no relation with your current one.